# Type Hierarchy for Containers Values confusing

Tags: julia

`Integer` is a super type of `Int64`. Hence, the following should work

```
function foo(a::Integer)
    return 42
end

foo(2)
```

and indeed it does:

```
42
```

The method used is

```
@which foo(2)
foo(a::Integer)
```

But why then is the same not possible for an array/vector?

```
function bar(a::Vector{Integer})
    return 42
end

bar([2, 3])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching bar(::Array{Int64,1})
```